# How to add a pattern="" to elements with a specific class via jQuery

Tags: jquery

There are plenty of instructions on how to add extra classes to specific elements, but what dom element would I use to add (for example) `pattern="[0-9]*"` to all input elements with the class of `.number`?

I'm new to JavaScript so any direction is helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$(".number").attr('pattern', '[0-9]*');`